# How to put a symbol above another in LaTeX?

Tags: latex

How to put a symbol above (on the head of) another? For example, I want to produce something like this in one line.

```
a
#
```

i.e., `a` above `#`.

The effect should be almost the same with `$#^a$` except that `a` is on the top instead of top right of `#`.

Comment: Do you want them both to be the same size? And how should they appear in relation to the surrounding text? Should the # be in line with the text, or should the midpoint between a and # be in line with it?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Artelius. About their size, the above one is smaller would be preferred. The effect should be the same as $#^a$ except that 'a' is on the top of '#' other than on the top right of '#'.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the reminder. Gonna read the FAQ.

Comment: This was closed as off topic. I think it should be migrated to TeX.se. It may not be able to, because it's too old. At the time of its posting it was accepted that LaTeX was a programming language and that such questions were welcome here.

Comment: For future: http://tex.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Use `\overset{above}{main}` in math mode. In your case, `\overset{a}{\#}`.

Comment: In case there is no AsmTex: `\stackrel{a}{\#}`

Answer (score 26):

```
${a \atop \#}$
```

or

```
${a \above 0pt \#}$
```

Comment: Alexey, LaTeX complains the two commands are foreign. Also, the two symbols are put equal size which is not what I wanted. Artelius's answer matches my needs perfectly.  Anyway, thank you all the same.

Answer (score 25):

If you're using `#` as an operator, consider defining a new operator for it:

```
\newcommand{\pound}{\operatornamewithlimits{\#}}
```

You can then write things like `\pound_{n = 1}^N` and get:

[image]